# Apply regular expression to a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Im trying to apply some regular expressions that I have coded up and can run against a variable but I would like to apply it on a dataframe column and then pass the results out to a new column

```
df["Details"] is my dataframe
```

df["Details"] is my dataframe and it contains some text similar to what I have created below as details

```
import re
details = '1st: Batman 01:12.98 11.5L'

position = re.search('\w\w\w:\s', details)
distance = re.search('(\s\d\d.[0-9]L)', details)
time = re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2}',details)

print(position.group(0))
print(distance.group(0))
print(time.group(0))
```

```
output is then 
    1st: 
    11.5L
    01:12.98
```

I would like to then be able to add those values to new columns in the dataframe called position,distance,time respectively matching the output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
details = '1st: Batman 01:12.98 11.5L'

df = pd.DataFrame({"Details":[details,details,details]})

df['position'] = df['Details'].str.extract(r'(\w\w\w:\s)')
df['distance'] = df['Details'].str.extract(r'(\s\d\d.[0-9]L)')
df['time'] = df['Details'].str.extract(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2})')
print(df)

                      Details position distance      time
0  1st: Batman 01:12.98 11.5L    1st:     11.5L  01:12.98
1  1st: Batman 01:12.98 11.5L    1st:     11.5L  01:12.98
2  1st: Batman 01:12.98 11.5L    1st:     11.5L  01:12.98
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply extract in lambda function:

```
df['position'] = df['Details'].apply(lambda x: str(x).extract(r'(\w\w\w:\s)')))
df['distance'] = df['Details'].apply(lambda x: str(x).extract(r'(\s\d\d.[0-9]L)'))
df['time'] = df['Details'].apply(lambda x: str(x).extract(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2})'))
```